# Jetty server throws idle timeout for REST calls

Tags: java, rest, web-services, timeout, jetty

I have a very simple code snippet to test Jetty server 9.4.41. In the debug level logs I see Timeout Exceptions. I know it is related to idle timeout, and it happens when there is no read/write activity on the connection. But I am just wondering, am I supposed to get the exceptions in the logs? It looks like to me something is not right. I would appreciate if somebody can help to understand why I am getting this.

Here is my Jetty server code:

```
public class JettyServer {
    private Server server;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8090);
        connector.setIdleTimeout(30000);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});

        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/example");
        handler.addServlet(ExampleServlet.class, "/");

        server.start();
    }
}
```

My Main method just starts this server, and ExampleServlet.class just return a simple success response for the requests: `{ "status": "ok"}`. It takes only 50ms to respond (with any REST client, or calling the API using browser).

Here is the servlet code that generates the response:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        response.getWriter().println("{ \"status\": \"ok\"}");
    }
}
```

Here is the exceptions I see in debug level logs:

```
2021-05-30 02:49:42.979:DBUG:oeji.IdleTimeout:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=29990/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} idle timeout check, elapsed: 29989 ms, remaining: 11 ms
2021-05-30 02:49:42.995:DBUG:oeji.IdleTimeout:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30005/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30005 ms, remaining: -5 ms
2021-05-30 02:49:42.996:DBUG:oeji.IdleTimeout:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30006/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} idle timeout expired
2021-05-30 02:49:42.997:DBUG:oeji.FillInterest:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: onFail FillInterest@2864451e{AC.ReadCB@45004b9a{HttpConnection@45004b9a::SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30007/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}}
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30005/30000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-05-30 02:49:42.997:DBUG:oejh.HttpParser:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: close HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}
2021-05-30 02:49:42.997:DBUG:oejh.HttpParser:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: START --> CLOSE
2021-05-30 02:49:42.997:DBUG:oeji.AbstractConnection:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: HttpConnection@45004b9a::SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=30008/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} onFillInterestedFailed {}
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30005/30000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-05-30 02:49:42.998:DBUG:oeji.AbstractEndPoint:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: shutdownOutput SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=30008/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
2021-05-30 02:49:42.999:DBUG:oeji.AbstractConnection:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: fillInterested HttpConnection@45004b9a::SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=30009/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
2021-05-30 02:49:42.999:DBUG:oeji.FillInterest:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: interested FillInterest@2864451e{AC.ReadCB@45004b9a{HttpConnection@45004b9a::SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}}
2021-05-30 02:49:43.000:DBUG:oeji.ChannelEndPoint:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: changeInterests p=false 1->1 for SocketChannelEndPoint@976b06a{l=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8090,r=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58250,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@45004b9a[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@3d68f9d0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@d49259c{s=HttpChannelState@484bba51{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
2021-05-30 02:49:43.000:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: Queued change lazy=false org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$$Lambda$86/0x0000000100123840@6f7f8713 on ManagedSelector@1e730495{STARTED} id=2 keys=1 selected=0 updates=0
2021-05-30 02:49:43.000:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@1e730495{STARTED} id=2 keys=1 selected=0 updates=1
2021-05-30 02:49:43.001:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:qtp157683534-19: Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@1a6c75fe woken with none selected
2021-05-30 02:49:43.001:DBUG:oeji.WriteFlusher:Connector-Scheduler-289d1c02-1: ignored: WriteFlusher@3f9371c0{IDLE}->null
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30005/30000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-05-30 02:49:43.001:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:qtp157683534-19: Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@1a6c75fe woken up from select, 0/0/1 selected
2021-05-30 02:49:43.001:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:qtp157683534-19: Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@1a6c75fe processing 0 keys, 1 updates
2021-05-30 02:49:43.001:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:qtp157683534-19: updateable 1
2021-05-30 02:49:43.002:DBUG:oeji.ManagedSelector:qtp157683534-19: update org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$$Lambda$86/0x0000000100123840@6f7f8713
```

Here is the request and response details:

Request:

```
(GET //localhost:8090/example/)
Accept */*
User-Agent PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Connection keep-alive
Postman-Token 83c2a08e-d881-4f94-993d-aa39d3342dd3
Host localhost:8090
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length 1
Content-Type application/json
Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 15:40:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
```

Reponse:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Date Tue, 01 Jun 2021 15:40:46 GMT
Content-Type application/json
```

Comment: Those are DEBUG level events, with no details on the requests being made, or the responses being produced.  There are literally millions of reasons for those idle timeouts.  If you want specific details, please edit your question to include either the raw request and raw response being produced, or the request/response details from the DEBUG logs themselves.

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated the question to include the servlet code that generates the response (it does not do much, just returns with { "status": "ok"}). Please let me know if more information needs to be provided.

Comment: I don't see where you included the raw request and response details. (ie: the "GET ..." and "200 OK ..." with headers included)

Comment: I just added the request and response details

Comment: I guess it should be something related related to keep-alive flag in the request header, correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess it should be something related related to keep-alive flag in the request header, correct me if I am wrong

`Connection: keep-alive` means nothing in HTTP/1.1, as that's exclusively an `HTTP/1.0` concept.

That value (`keep-alive`) is ignored by Jetty when the request line contains `HTTP/1.1`, and the resulting header is basically an header without a meaningful value (aka, default behavior for HTTP/1.1)

The request you made is for a persistent connection (the default behavior in HTTP/1.1), the response for the server also maintains that persistent connection.

The fact that you get a idle timeout is for the connection itself, not for any particular request, and is normal behavior for persistent connections that are not closed.

Note that the specific idle timeout you see is a DEBUG level event, and is not a warning/failure or anything else.  Those would be logged at WARN level (or higher).

You can easily add a `Connection: close` to the request and the connection will be closed.

You can also add `Connection: close` on the server side and the response will be sent then the connection is closed.

Comment: Removing "Connection: keep-alive" header from the request in Postman, or changing it to "Connection: close" resolved the issue, I am not getting the timeout anymore.

Comment: So what does it mean if we do get those idleTimeout messages at WARN level? ('cause I am)

Comment: The question here includes a log that shows DEBUG idle timeouts.  I would suggest you open a new question with your logs showing WARN (if there are stacktraces, be sure to include them).